# Buffer I/O error on device (sata drive)

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I keep getting these messages in one of my servers kernel logs (which is responsible for file operations). I wonder if anybody knows how serious are these issues. I cannot use smartmontools because the disks are handled by a 3ware card which has it's own (very limited tw_cli utility).

```
[2522065.275739] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg] CDB: 
[2522065.275741] Read(10): 28 00 2e 90 97 f8 00 00 08 00
[2522065.275750] end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 781228024
[2522065.281091] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 97653503
[2522065.287157] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg] Device not ready
[2522065.287163] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.287166] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[2522065.287168] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.287170] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[2522065.287174] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.287176] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
[2522065.287179] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg] CDB: 
[2522065.287181] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[2522065.287190] end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 0
[2522065.291147] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 0
[2522065.291147] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 1
[2522065.291147] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 2
[2522065.308465] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg] Device not ready
[2522065.308465] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.308465] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[2522065.308465] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.308465] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[2522065.308465] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg]  
[2522065.308465] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
[2522065.308465] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdg] CDB: 
[2522065.308465] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[2522065.308465] end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use smart values:
for example:

```
 smartctl -a -d 3ware,2 /dev/twe0
```

Qouting the manpage of smartctl:

```
Under Linux and FreeBSD, to look at ATA disks behind 3ware SCSI RAID controllers, use syntax such as:
          smartctl -a -d 3ware,2 /dev/sda
          smartctl -a -d 3ware,0 /dev/twe0
          smartctl -a -d 3ware,1 /dev/twa0
          where in the argument 3ware,N, the integer N is the disk number (3ware ´port´) within the 3ware ATA RAID controller.  The allowed values of N are from 0  to  31  inclusive.   The  first  two
          forms,  which  refer to devices /dev/sda-z and /dev/twe0-15, may be used with 3ware series 6000, 7000, and 8000 series controllers that use the 3x-xxxx driver.  Note that the /dev/sda-z form
          is deprecated starting with the Linux 2.6 kernel series and may not be supported by the Linux kernel in the near future. The final form, which refers to devices /dev/twa0-15,  must  be  used
          with 3ware 9000 series controllers, which use the 3w-9xxx driver.

          Note  that  if the special character device nodes /dev/twa? and /dev/twe? do not exist, or exist with the incorrect major or minor numbers, smartctl will recreate them on the fly.  Typically
          /dev/twa0 refers to the first 9000-series controller, /dev/twa1 refers to the second 9000 series controller, and so on. Likewise /dev/twe0 refers to  the  first  6/7/8000-series  controller,
          /dev/twa1 refers to the second 6/7/8000 series controller, and so on.
```

For some ideas about your question:

This might not yet be a full blown issue with the HDD/SSD, but i suggest changing it ASAP.

Make backups if you not have done it yet!

You can check for a problem with something like:

```
e2fsck -fv /dev/sdX
```

If you see reallocated sectors within smart you should change the drive in my opinion.

Comment: I second the statement about the reallocated sectors. When a drive starts doing that, they don't last long.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the smart information using (for example):

```
smartctl -a -d 3ware,N /dev/twa0
```

N is the port nr, twa0 the controller.

With the following you can obtain some interface error statistics:

```
smartctl -l sataphy -d 3ware,N /dev/twa0
```

With that command, I was able to determine that 'ata exceptions' I kept getting in my logs were the result of interface/cable errors, because the CRC counts increased (which ultimately required replacing the disks with a different type. Replacing the mainboard with the same type didn't help). Looking at it, a normal SATA controller gives you more information than a a 3Ware port.

As for the 'buffer error', I've never had that one, so I can't speculate. I have had numerous 'ata exceptions' in the past (on software RAID), which was almost always a precursor to failure. Therefore, I scan my logs for that now.